# Condition in Rest-Assured

Tags: rest-assured

I am looking for a way to implement conditional verification in Rest Assured. Suppose if I get a response body as

```
{
"id": 1,
"accounts": [
  {
    "accountType": "Type1",
    "properties": {}
  },
  {
    "accountType": "Type2",
    "properties": {}
  }
]
```

}

I have check for presence of "accounts" first. We can do that by

```
given().when().get("url").then().body().("any { it.key == 'accounts' }"), is(true))
```

Then I need to verify size of the accounts array if accounts exists in the response body. Is there any condition I can use here like

```
if(accountsExists) {Check for Array.size();} else {do something}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do this but I would highly recommend not to (because it's complex and is using undocumented features). For example let's say you want to return the size of `accounts` if it exists and if it doesn't exists you want to return the value of `id` instead:

```
get("url").then().body("accounts?.size() ?: restAssuredJsonRootObject.id"), anyOf(is(2), is(1)));
```

Explanation:

**accounts?.size()** means it should return the size of the accounts list IF it exists (i.e. is not null)

**?:** Is the [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator#Groovy) which will return the size of the account OR what we write on the right-hand side.

**restAssuredJsonRootObject.id** means that we want to return the `id` from the root of the document. The root of the document is referred to as `restAssuredJsonRootObject` (which is not documented and is subject to change).

What I would do instead is to create two different tests. One where you know that `accounts` is present and one where it's not present.

Comment: Thanks Johan for the answer and the explanation. And Yes, I used same approach in my automation like creating 2 test cases for each of them.

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Please mark it as answered if you find it appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much privilege to do so but I already voted and will show up whenever I get enough privilege.